# Kids’ picture book about a crash-landed rocket and a robot boy on another planet

Tags: story-identification, books, robots

A long time ago, around when I was in kindergarten (2006ish) I remember reading a book (or rather, looking at the pictures) from the school library. It was a picture book set on another planet, with very detailed illustrations of the planet and its inhabitants.

I seem to remember all of the characters and settings being made entirely of translucent or semi-translucent goo or slime. There were bright, bold colours throughout the whole book, deep primaries and variations thereof. It looked like everything had a black background, lending to a space-like image/feel.

I vaguely remember something about a crash landed rocket and a robot boy, but other than that I have no idea what the plot could’ve possibly been. The illustrations are what stuck out to me most, but no matter how many times I describe them in a Google search nothing turns up.

I’m fairly certain the book was probably from at least a few years before I ever read it, maybe from the 90’s, but I could be wrong. It was a very visually interesting book, which is probably why it’s stuck in my memory for so long, even though I don’t have a clue what it was about.